# Translation for an existing Zend website

Tags: zend-framework

I need your opinion please about the best way to make a transalation with two languages,in fact I'm working on a big site already builded using zend 1.9 and it's on line from a long time,but with no transalation of language,now after years the client want to add other languages,I know that I can use zend_translate and zend route to do it,but my issue is the best way and easy way to make it and like I said it's a big project,finally with static text I guess is simple with zend_translate but the bad thing is with dynamic text from database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct in thinking that Zend Translate will be the best way of approaching this. The following section on the Zend website will be helpful:

http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.translate.html

The 'dynamic' aspect that you've highlighted is not something that is supported out-the-box but you'd likely have to rely on the database for the translation look-ups too. I came across the following post on the Zend forums that may be of use:

http://forums.zend.com/viewtopic.php?f=69&t=6036